# What should I look for when purchasing a Laser diode with good coherence?

Tags: experimental-physics, laser, interferometry, coherence

I want to purchase laser diodes that will work well for interferometry. I have been using inexpensive laser diode modules that I buy from of Amazon for 2 or 3 dollars each. For the most part they create good interference patterns, but they are not very consistent. Most work well in a Michelson setup but only some perform well when in a Mach-Zehnder configuration. I'd like the laser to be red, focusable, less than 5mW and run off of a battery pack. Any advice you can offer is greatly appreciated. I'm willing to spend up to 50.00 each. What should I look for when selecting a laser diode for interferometry?